# quickfix: how to convert FIX::Account to a c_string or other types

Tags: c++, quickfix

I am using quickfixengine to build a FIX application. quickfix almost has no documentation, pretty much like a blackhole. I have a variable which is a `FIX::Account` type. I know it is a FIX string type, but how do I get the string out (to be a c-string). I tried something like this, it does not pass the compilation.

```
FIX::Account acct;

// populate  acct somewhere else

printf(acct.c_str());
```

Compiler error is error: ‘class FIX::Account’ has no member named ‘c_str’

basically, I'd like to know how to get to know the constructor, interface of every FIX types? which files contain these?

thank you

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're using the C++ API. In this case, all fields inherit from `FIX::FieldBase` which has a convenient `getString()` method (see [here](http://www.quickfixengine.org/quickfix/doc/html/class_f_i_x_1_1_field_base.html#ab23b10cf8730f51aa42eedd0342641b6)).

I agree that is not easy to understand at a glance the declarations of FIX fields. That's because all classes related to FIX messages are directly generated from the XML specifications of the FIX protocol.

Answer (score 1):

getValue() method should be used for getting string fields.
printf(acct.getValue().c_str());

Hope this helps.